# Sorting by tournament sort

Tags: sorting

Is there somewhere a website/application/software/something where you can submit a list of string/image/audio/content/whatever and the appliance make a tournament sort by asking you question like "Do you prefer [Element K] or [Element J] or you don't know?". And depending on the replies he ask smartly for the other elements of the list and when he has enough replies, he return a sorted list of our string/image/audio/content/whatever preferences? ([ex-aequo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_aequo_et_bono#Ex_aequo) can be possible considering the "you don't know" choice)

It's not a software creation asking, it's a "simple thing" that I guess it exists over internet, but I don't know what terms to search for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://ihaque.org/posts/2019/04/07/interactive-preference-ranking/#live-demo-interactive-preference-ranking) might be helpful. There might be other websites too.

Comment: Yeah it seems pretty much to be that. I will maybe have to modify the code myself to make it more user friendly because for now it's really messy. Thanks